# Any other way to put a value next to build name except 'teamcity.build.branch'?

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

Is there any other way to put a value next to build name except 'teamcity.build.branch'?

[image]

I need to specify a metadata next to each build that might be dynamic or might be result from a previous build configuration part of the build chain using TC SNAPSHOT dependencies.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the TeamCity 9.x documentation, there's no other way to add a "label to each build" except via the `teamcity.build.branch` parameter.
For Git & Mercurial, TeamCity provides additional parameters with the names of VCS branches known at the moment of build start via `teamcity.build.vcs.branch.<VCS root ID>`.
If you just want to add a human-friendly description, you could try `teamcity.build.triggeredBy` and `teamcity.build.triggeredBy.username`.

I see you've already asked this question on the JetBrains forums and been directed to a [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-15905) on JetBrain's YouTrack. Oleg Gerovich mentions using the "triggered by" column there.

It might be possible to create a plugin to do what you want.
*Now remember, you're only asking if it's possible in your question. Feel free to update your question.* ;)